# How do I plot points from two lists using turtle graphic programming?

Tags: python, plot, turtle-graphics

I want to use turtle graphics to plot points onto a graph using two lists.

x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
y = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

When I try to put the lists into a loop to plot onto the turtle screen that i customized, it keeps giving me an error. I am an entry level programmer,  so please no advanced code. This is for an intro to computer science class.

```
import turtle

s = turtle.Screen()

t = turtle.Turtle()

s.title('Canvas')


s.setup(width = 0.5, height = 0.5, startx=0, starty=0)


s.setworldcoordinates(-2,-2,12,12)



x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

y = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]


for i in range(x,y):
    t.goto(x[0],y[0])
    t.dot()
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, it's not a good idea to keep the x and y coords in different lists. You have to ensure each list has the same number of elements (or handle the cases where they don't). You could [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) them together into a single list, or just create a list of tuples:

```
coords = [(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4),(5,5),(6,6),(7,7),(8,8),(9,9),(10,10)]
for c in coords:
    t.goto(c[0], c[1])
    t.dot()
```

But if you really want to use 2 lists:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
y = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
for i in range(len(x)):
    t.goto(x[i], y[i])
    t.dot()
```

Comment: Thank you so much!